# Matlab does NOT release gpu memory if interp3 is called

Tags: matlab, gpu

I am working with Matlab 2016a and Nvidia Geforce GTX Titan X (12GB gpu memory), but the problem is valid for 2015a,b and 2014b on both windows and linux with the same graphics card. The sample code is very straightforward, if I create a large chunk of gpu memory and use "clear all" to release it without calling interp3, its fine. However, if interp3 is called, the memory will NOT be released by "clear all". Is there a way to release the memory?

```
[Xq,Yq,Zq] = meshgrid(1:14,1:14, 1:256);
feature_map_padG = gpuArray(single(rand(195, 83, 256)));
featG = gpuArray(single(rand(14, 14, 256, 5500)));
clear all% OK, it can be released

[Xq,Yq,Zq] = meshgrid(1:14,1:14, 1:256);
feature_map_padG = gpuArray(single(rand(195, 83, 256)));
featG = gpuArray(single(rand(14, 14, 256, 5500)));
interp3(feature_map_padG,Xq,Yq,Zq);
clear all % NO! it can NOT be released!
```

Comment: maybe http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/reset.html will help.

Comment: thanks for the reply, however I need a method to preserve some of the gpuarray elsewhere, not just clear them all...

Comment: How are you deducing that the memory cannot be released? Are you looking at the `AvailableMemory` field of the `GPUDevice` object? What values do you see for the two cases?

Comment: In tried in both windows and ubuntu. In windows, I looked at the memory showed in the software GPU-Z, in ubuntu I used the command "nvidia-smi -l" to see the gpu memory.